# Event called when gridview/listview have been populated

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-gridview, android-adapter

With a complex adapter, `GridView`s and `ListView`s can sometimes take a long time to populate after calling the `setAdapter()` method. Is there a method we can override that is triggered when the view has been successfully populated with data and is ready to be shown?

Comment: Could you post the code of the adapter?

Comment: No, its not ready to be shown, and its shown when its ready... :)  Async out complex tasks like loading images.  You can spawn a worker thread in the GetView, or have a general one you'r passing work to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that it isn't the `setAdapter()` that takes a long time, but rather that the complex adapter is doing something complex. The ListView and GridViews are specified to work rather quickly, but there's a few reasons they might be slower. Here's a few thoughts as to how to work this one out.

1. Figure out what's taking so long. Network calls, large database queries, and loading large files (Bitmaps in particular) are often the guilty party. If you don't have any of those, try profiling your code, and see what you can gleam from that.
2. Once you've figured out the culprit, see what you can do to decrease the amount of time. Perhaps shrinking the size of a bitmap, or using a better database query would work.
3. If you can't shrink the time down any more, then do the complex task in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This will do the complex part of your code in the background, and only show the result when it is complete. This works well for things like network calls, loading bitmaps, etc.

Comment: I already had an `AsyncTask` doing the network operations to get the data in the first place. Not sure why I didn't just put the `setAdapter()` method inside of that. Duuurrrrrrr, my bad.

Comment: It's probably better to put the lengthy components of the Adapter into an AsyncTask rather than the call to the `setAdapter`, but...

Comment: I can't put the `setAdapter` inside the `AsyncTask` because it returns the error `Only the original thread that created the view hierachy can touch it's views.` However what I've done is instantiate the adapter inside the `AsyncTask` and put the `setAdapter` code in the `onPostExecute` function. Works much better now - cheers.